# Laravel - Relate to same pivot table twice

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I am currently working on a site and I've decided to move it over from CodeIgniter to Laravel mainly because of the RESTful architecture and because I need to connect with another company site with an API.

The problem I'm running into currently is thus:

I have a user, and user can have two addresses: billing or shipping.  However, user can also have no assigned addresses.  So basically here's what it looks like in the database:

```
-User
--id
--name, phone, etc...

-UserAddress
--id
--user_id
--billing_address_id
--shipping_address_id

-Address
--id
--street, city, state, etc...
```

So Address links to UserAddress twice via billing or shipping address id, so what is the relationship between these three tables in Laravel 4?  I'm fairly new to Laravel and coding in general, so I'd like some pointers in how to go about getting this kind of relationship set up properly, considering this relationship also happens with some other tables and Address as well.

Note: User and Address have no foreign keys in them, you can consider them as base-line tables.  Anything that needs a user links to the User table, as well, anything that needs an address stores that address in the Address table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up having to figure it out on my own, after waiting an entire month for an answer.

I finally just ended up going into the address table and adding an address_type field, which allowed me to specify whether or not it was billing, shipping, or both.  So my pivot table changed to simply three fields of id, user_id, and address_id, then I used logic in my controller to handle reading the fields and finding out what the address type was and acting accordingly.

All in all it ended up looking something like this:

```
-User
--id
--username
--password
--email
--etc...

-User_pvt_address
--id
--user_id
--address_id

-Address
--id
--address_1
--address_2
--city
--state
--country_id
--postal_code
--address_type

-Address_Type
--id
--type
```